# Как склеить два парсера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bs4

У меня есть 2 парсера. Один парсит заголовок, дату, текст страницы.
**Вот 1 код парсера**

```
#Парсер v0 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    text=soup.find('p').text
    date=soup.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    textp=soup.find_all('p')




    return  (title,text,date,str (textp))

def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4980160-nazvana-data-nachala-kurban-ayta-v-2019.html'
    (get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

А вот второй парсер который парсит [эту страницу](https://www.zakon.kz/news/) Он там собирает ссылки новостей. 
**Вот  код 2 парсера**

```
#Парсер v1 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
    print(str.strip(title))


    counter = 0
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1
    print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    get_page_link(get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Как склеить эти парсеры чтобы второй кидал первому ссылки и первый парсил эти ссылки?

Comment: Склеить очень просто. Нужно только взять учебник по питону и прочитать пару глав.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы в обоих скриптах подписались как их автор. Неужели склеить не сможете? Казалось бы, самое сложное-то вы уже сделали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде, так должно работать. Не могу сейчас проверить код. Если будет ошибка, скиньте в комментарий, поправлю.

```
#Парсер v2 by Raha
import traceback
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
    print(str.strip(title))

    counter = 0
    links_rcv = []
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            links_rcv.append(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
            #print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1
    print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")
    return links_rcv


def get_context_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    text=soup.find('p').text
    date=soup.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    textp=soup.find_all('p')
    return (title,text,date,str (textp))


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    links_rcv = get_page_link(get_html(url))
    for i in links_rcv:
        try:
            print(get_context_data(get_context_html(i)))
        except:
            print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
            print(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

З.Ы. Если собираетесь серьезно заниматься подобными вещами, обратите внимание на `scrapy`.